# OpenGL array of points

Tags: arrays, opengl, graphics, 3d

I have the following code to draw an array of points but it only draws one point in the center.  How can I draw an array of 2D points using OpenGL?

```
GLint NumberOfPoints = 10;
GLfloat x[2],y[2];

glBegin( GL_POINTS );

for ( int i = 0; i < NumberOfPoints; ++i )
{
    glVertex2f( x[i], y[i] );

}
glEnd();
```

Comment: Oops I've just realized some other problems would cause you don't see what you draw. Is this your ONLY code about drawing or OpenGL? I mean,  you MUST have a working 'OpenGL context' to let OpenGL work. Merely do with things like `glBegin` and `glVertex2f` won't actually work. For newbies [glut](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/glut.htm) is a good choice for setting an OpenGL context.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice. Update the original if you have anything new to add.

Comment: You're not only new to OpenGL but programming in general, aren't you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where are you setting the values for x[0], x[1], y[0], and y[1]?

If it's only drawing one point in the center, it sounds like the values are set to 0 for all four of those variables.  Be sure to initialize their values before you reference them in your call to gVertex2f().

Comment: @ArledKola: Isn't it important that you initialize variables with data? OpenGL cannot magically know what you want to draw. You have to tell it what to draw, and you do that by passing known values to OpenGL. If you don't initialize your variables, then you aren't passing _known_ values; you're passing random garbage.

Comment: could u show me how to do it  please im trying so hard im new to opengl and its driving me crazy

Comment: @ArledKola: Initializing data has nothing to do with OpenGL. It's a basic programming task. If you've still strugling with the concept of initializing memory, then I suggest you first get your programming basics straight, before tackling a complex API like OpenGL.

Answer (score 10):

Requires [GLUT](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/) for window and context management:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

struct Point
{
    float x, y;
    unsigned char r, g, b, a;
};
std::vector< Point > points;

void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-50, 50, -50, 50, -1, 1);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    // draw
    glColor3ub( 255, 255, 255 );
    glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
    glEnableClientState( GL_COLOR_ARRAY );
    glVertexPointer( 2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Point), &points[0].x );
    glColorPointer( 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, sizeof(Point), &points[0].r );
    glPointSize( 3.0 );
    glDrawArrays( GL_POINTS, 0, points.size() );
    glDisableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
    glDisableClientState( GL_COLOR_ARRAY );

    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE);

    glutInitWindowSize(640,480);
    glutCreateWindow("Random Points");

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);

     // populate points
    for( size_t i = 0; i < 1000; ++i )
    {
        Point pt;
        pt.x = -50 + (rand() % 100);
        pt.y = -50 + (rand() % 100);
        pt.r = rand() % 255;
        pt.g = rand() % 255;
        pt.b = rand() % 255;
        pt.a = 255;
        points.push_back(pt);
    }    

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: is it possible to get them moving across the screen so the keep re-appearing as well

Comment: How comes my "random picture" looks exactly the same as this one? I am aware that you can change this by using srand()

Comment: @kometonja: ["If `rand()` is used before any calls to `srand()`, `rand()` behaves as if it was seeded with `srand(1)`."](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand)  And if you're also using GCC then [the `rand()` implementation and LCG parameters are likely the same](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#Parameters_in_common_use).

Answer (score 1):

Do you define what x[i] and y[i] are? Otherwise they will be set to 0 automatically (hence the centering). Also, creating the arrays with two elements but accessing 10 elements is very bad since you are accessing memory locations that you do not have control over.

You should do something like :

```
GLint NumberOfPoints = 10;
GLfloat x[10],y[10];

for(int i = 0; i < NumberOfPoints; i++){
    x[i] = y[i] = (GLfloat) i;
}

glBegin( GL_POINTS );

for ( int i = 0; i < NumberOfPoints; ++i )
{
    glVertex2f( x[i], y[i] );

}
glEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code just works. Fill the array `x` and `y` with randomized values and this would draw random points.

The problem may be you can't 'see' the points you draw. That's obvious since:

1. By default the color of the points is black( 0, 0, 0, in rgb), and you may want to set it to some other value using `glColor3f` or such functions.
2. You've drawn too few points and each point is too small(actually only 1 pixel size on your screen). You may want to draw circles instead or draw thousand or more pixels and check again.

By the way, please format your question and let the code displayed normally.

---

**Edited:**

See my comment above. If you didn't set up a valid OpenGL context or you just didn't know how, check this http://openglbook.com/the-book/chapter-1-getting-started/ and get started with your first working OpenGL program.

Comment: @ArledKola Have your read my answers and others' comment on your another question? What do you mean here? I know how to draw 10 random points or show your full code and I'll make it work. The problem now is YOU DIDN'T MAKE IT CLEAR what the problem is. And I'm trying to clarify. You can't expect a random result from an uninitialized array. It's okay if you just comment like this and keep your problems unsolved.

Comment: @ArledKola And I don't feel any happy to get such response while trying to help you.